# What does Einstein mean by saying that equations of transformation are homogeneous?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics, affine-geometry

My question arises from reading Einstein's [The Meaning of Relativity](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Relativity/Lecture_1).  In particular, on page 12:

> If the three components of a vector vanish for one system of Cartesian co-ordinates, they vanish for all systems, because the equations of transformation are **homogeneous**.

And again on page 13:

In my notation the transformation under discussion is of the form

$$a_{\overline{i}\overline{j}}
=e_{\:\overline{i}}^{i}e_{\:\overline{j}}^{j}a_{ij}.$$

> This transformation is **homogeneous** and of the first degree in the $a_{\mu\nu}.$

So, with that added background, here is the original formulation of my question: In Euclidean 3-space, we are given various rectangular Cartesian coordinate system all of the same scale, and related by transformation equations of the form

$$x^{\overline{i}}=a^{\overline{i}}+e_{\:i}^{\overline{i}}x^{i},$$

with the determinant $\left|e_{\:i}^{\overline{i}}\right|=1.$

What does it mean to say that the equations of transformation are homogeneous?  In particular what does it mean to say *if the components of a vector vanish in any of these coordinate systems, they vanish in all of these coordinate systems, **because the equations of transformation are homogeneous***?

To me, *homogeneous* applies to systems of linear equations or differential equations.  And the short definition is that the right-hand side is zero.

Comment: Generally speaking homogeneous means all of the same degree (when applied to graded rings generally and polynomials in particular). Here what he means is linear as opposed to affine.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function

Comment: Ah!  I should have recognized that.  I don't have to follow the link.  This is the meaning used in Euler's homogeneous function theorem.  If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: BTW: Einstein apparently uses the idiomatic slang of calling all affine transformation "linear".  That is, to Einstein: $x^{\overline{i}}=a^{\overline{i}}+e_{\:i}^{\overline{i}}x^{i}$ is *linear*.